# Search for c++ classes inheriting another class

Tags: c++, linux, bash, search

Is there a way to search with a bash script (using `grep`, `awk`, `sed`, ... too) for classes (or structs) inheriting a given base class?

I had a call like following in mind:

`./get_classes.sh 'CBaseClass' src/`

**Edit 1:**

What I've tried already:

`grep -r ':.*CBaseClass' src/`

This solution works, but only when there isn't any newline between `:` and `CBaseClass`.
Another problem here is, that when you have two classes in the same header that both inherit CBaseClass, grep will default to a greedy match (from fist `:` to second `CBaseClass`).

Comment: That's a peculiar question, I'll admit...why not expand your searchquery by `: public` and make it look only in header files? That way, you may be able to find all classes, which inherit from that one, without actually finding the class itself.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought/tried first, but what do you do, if there are newlines or other classes between `:` and `public/protected/private CBaseClass`?

Comment: You could look into using [libclang and Python](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang/) to actually do a semantic search.

Comment: Thanks! Actually a pretty good Idea though I do not have lots of  experience with python... Let's see if a bash-related answer comes, if not, I'll look into this. ;)

Comment: Why is it not good if there is a greedy match? I thought you just wanted to find the pattern anyway?

Comment: No. I want to see know what classes/structs inherit CBaseClass.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
find src/ \( -name \*.h -o -name \*.cpp -o -name \*.cxx \) -exec egrep '(class|struct).*:.*public.*CBaseClass'{} \; -print
```

to execute when you call `get_classes.sh  'CBaseClass' src/`

Comment: Well... First of all, thanks! But that is basically the same as using `grep -r <pattern> src/*,{h,cpp,cxx}` (Already tried this, sorry for the unclear post). The problem with this solution: It does not find the class, if there are newlines or other classes between `:` and the inherited class.